# byte array в string как "0" и "1"

Tags: java

Как преобразовать массив битов в текстовый вид так, чтобы это выглядело как набор из 0 и 1?

Если попытаться использовать метод `bytes.ToString()` то получается вот это: `[B@a0e2ce5`, а мне нужно **условно** `101100110101`

Есть ли готовый стандартный метод такого преобразования?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вариант на `stream api`:

   ```java
   Byte[] bytes = {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1};
   Arrays.stream(bytes).forEach((b) -> System.out.print(b));
   // 101100110101
   ```

   Добавляем к нему `method reference`:

   ```java
   Byte[] bytes = {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1};
   Arrays.stream(bytes).forEach(System.out::print);
   // 101100110101
   ```
2. Если нужен именно массив `byte[]`:

   ```java
   byte[] bytes = {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1};
   for (int b : bytes) System.out.print(b);
   // 101100110101
   ```
3. Если нужно красиво оформить:

   ```java
   byte[] bytes = {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1};
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
   // [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Есть рядом с упомянутым методом и [Integer.toBinaryString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))

Только обратите внимание, что лидирующие нули обрезаются, так что при необходимости дополняйте нулями вручную

Кроме того, `toString` принимает аргумент `radix`

Answer (score 0):

Если твой массив состоит из нулей  и единиц, то так:
    `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(твой_массив));`